# SearXNG and NGINX - Remove unnecessary path in URL

Tags: nginx, uwsgi, searxng

I installed SearXNG on a Ubuntu 22.04 server with this [documentation](https://docs.searxng.org/admin/installation-scripts.html) and also followed the [NGINX setup](https://docs.searxng.org/admin/installation-nginx.html#installation-nginx).

The original searxng.conf was like this

```
location /searxng {

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
    
    proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header   Connection       $http_connection;
    
    # see flaskfix.py
    proxy_set_header   X-Scheme         $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   X-Script-Name    /searxng;
    
    # see limiter.py
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    
    # proxy_buffering  off;
    # proxy_request_buffering off;
    # proxy_buffer_size 8k;

}
```

but I was getting the default NGINX page at the root of my site `mydomain.net`, so I changed the first line to this

`location / {`

Also modified the default NGINX config to this

```
server {
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name _;
}
```

But now, even though the index of my search engine points to the right domain `mydomain.net,` when I search something it adds `/searxng` to the URL like this `mydomain.net/searxng/search?q=bamboo&...`

Also, when I click on the search icon, it takes me to the homepage but it keeps the URL as `mydomain.net/searxng`

Therefore, I need help to remove that `/searxng` from my URL.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by removing this line

```
proxy_set_header   X-Script-Name    /searxng;
```